# Postfix null client configuration for Multiple Domains

Tags: postfix, virtualhost, null-client

I'm setting up Postfix null clients on in a virtual hosting server for multiple domains.

I found some documentation about setting up Virtual Domain Hosting, the closest thing I could find to what I'm trying to do:
http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#forwarding

Since I'm setting up Null clients, I'm guessing the setup for Mail Forwarding Domains would work as well.
Is that correct?

If I'm not correct, can someone point me to some documentation that will get me going in the right direction.

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to achieve. I do not get the terminology you are using.

Comment: It would be great if you could explain your final setup. I don't get how to setup a null client that is able to send mails with multiple origins. (multiple domains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. Virtual forwarding is something like "rewriting" or renaming the recipient address.
If you don't need this but only relay all mails, without accepting mails from "outside" and without delivering mail locally - this is the definition of a nullmailer - then you can follow these instructions: http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client

**But beware!** Don't forget to configure SASL authentication if you want to relay mails from outside your local network. And it won't do any harm to setup SASL for all mails.